# Cannot populate object hierarchy when using Reactive extensions

Tags: wpf, prism, system.reactive

I'm new to Reactive extensions, so I don't know what's important to describe in the question.

I have WPF application that displays a hierarchy 5 levels deep in a treeView. The architecture uses Prism and MVVM. The code that builds the source data for the treeView takes about a minute to build up the object hierarchy for three top level nodes. Here are some specifics from my MVVM:

```
  private ObservableCollection<IDxStudioInstanceDto> _instanceList = null;
  public ObservableCollection<IDxStudioInstanceDto> InstanceList {
     get { return _instanceList; }
     set {
        _instanceList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("InstanceList");
     }

  private void DisplayDataFetch() {
     InstanceList = _businessFacade.InstanceListFetch();

     //foreach(var instance in InstanceList) {
     //   _businessFacade.InstanceHierarchyFetch(instance);
     //}

     var query = from instance in InstanceList
                 select instance;
     var observableSequence = query.ToObservable().SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).ObserveOnDispatcher();
     _subscribeInstanceHierarchy = observableSequence.Subscribe(instance => _businessFacade.InstanceHierarchyFetch(instance));
  }
```

The the MVVM method called 'DisplayDataFetch' does two things. It loads the the top-level nodes only into the ObservableCollection.

```
     InstanceList = _businessFacade.InstanceListFetch();
```

The remaining code, either the commented foreach loop or the Reactive Extension code below that, fill in each top-level node with the child hierarchy. Both use the same set of calls to build the hierarchy. I was expecting to have the treeView load quickly with the top-level nodes, then as the remaining child hierarchies are completed, be added to the displayed treeView.

If I run the entire process on the UI thread by substituting the commented foreach loop for the Reactive Extension code, the treeView displays the hierarchy as expected. Although the UI thread is blocked for about a minute.

If I run the Reactive Extension code the UI thread is blocked for about a minute and the top level nodes of the tree are 'naked', missing the entire child hierarchy.

I've tried without success the Scheduler.ThreadPool and removing the ObserveOnDispatch() portion of the observableSequence.

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem of 'naked' top-level nodes. It was an error with missing INotifyPropertyChanged on some child objects. Now it shows the full tree when done processing. However, it still blocks the UI thread until finished. The initial list of top-level nodes is not displayed when available then everything bursts onto the form at the end of processing, fully formed. I was expecting the initial list of top-level nodes to display, then be filled in as processing completes on each thread.         Am I not implementing SubscribeOn, and ObserveOnDispatch correctly?

Comment: The display of the initial list of top-level nodes is now working, an instrumentation issues. The UI is still blocked for about a minute while filling in the child nodes for each top-level node. All the top-level nodes are naked until the child node processing is finished for all of them, then they all display together. Why don't they fill in as each one completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is blocked because your observer/subscriber (`instance => _businessFacade.InstanceHierarchyFetch(instance)`) is running on the dispatcher.

I suggest you refactor your `InstanceHierarchyFetch` to return the results and not mutate the `IDxStudioInstanceDto` instance that is passed in. Then you could change your query to something like this:

```
var query = from instance in InstanceList.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)
            let hierarchy = FetchHierarchyFor(instance.Key)
            select new {instance, hierarchy};

query
  .ObserveOnDispatcher()
  .Subscribe(tuple => tuple.instance.UpdateHierarchy(tuple.hierarchy);
```

This way, the fetching will run in a background thread, while the mutating of your instances will run on the UI thread, to play nice with WPF and your data binding.

A few things you should notice about your original code:

- `SubscribeOn` does not do what you think it does. Read about it. What you wanted to use is `ObserveOn`.
- {`from instance in InstanceList select instance`} is equivalent to {`InstanceList`}. It's redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into all of this.

Comment: Sweet...!, thanks. Working with your answer has pushed me further down the road of using Rx.